# How can I combine multiple update statements into a single update statement?

Tags: sql-server

My question is this: is it possible to combine the following update statements into a single update statement without using CASE structure?

```
update A 
set A.colX = S.col3 
from tableA as A 
inner join sourceTable as S on A.col1 = S.col1 
where s.col2 = 'someValue_A';

update A 
set A.colY = S.col3 
from tableA as A 
inner join sourceTable as S on A.col1 = S.col1 
where s.col2 = 'someValue_B';

update A 
set A.colZ = S.col3 
from tableA as A 
inner join sourceTable as S on A.col1 = S.col1 
where s.col2 = 'someValue_C';
```

Comment: Where clause in Update gives the rows on which the update condition will run. If you want to update data on different conditions for different rows then you cant combine them

Comment: @user, that's incorrect.

Comment: without case also?

Comment: Why the limitation on the `CASE` expression? Seems a silly hinderance.

Answer (score 0):

You can update using case.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.colX = CASE 
        WHEN s.col2 = 'someValue_A'
            THEN s.col3
        ELSE a.colX
        END
    ,A.colY = CASE 
        WHEN s.col2 = 'someValue_B'
            THEN s.col3
        ELSE a.colY
        END
    ,A.colZ = CASE 
        WHEN s.col2 = 'someValue_C'
            THEN s.col3
        ELSE a.colZ
        END
FROM tableA AS A
INNER JOIN sourceTable AS S ON A.col1 = S.col1
WHERE s.col2 IN (
        'someValue_A'
        ,'someValue_B'
        ,'someValue_C '
        )
```

Or you can use `IIF` in the same way.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.colX = IIF(s.col2 = 'someValue_A', s.col3, a.colX)
    ,A.colY = IIF(s.col2 = 'someValue_B', s.col3, a.colY)
    ,A.colZ = IIF(s.col2 = 'someValue_C', s.col3, A.colZ)
FROM tableA AS A
INNER JOIN sourceTable AS S ON A.col1 = S.col1
WHERE s.col2 IN (
        'someValue_A'
        ,'someValue_B'
        ,'someValue_C '
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really only valuable as a thought exercise, or perhaps a homework assignment. The *correct* way to do this would be a conditional expression like `CASE` or `IIF`, and either that or the three separate statements would all far out-perform this combined query.

But in the interest of answering the "can it be done" question, it can be.

This will update all values of the three columns in `tableA`, either to their new values if one exists or to their current values if one does not, for every row where any of the three needs updating. The re-writing of all the extraneous values is why this is horribly inefficient.

That said:

```
UPDATE A 
  SET 
    colX = COALESCE(S1.col3, colX),
    colY = COALESCE(S2.col3, colY),
    colZ = COALESCE(S3.col3, colZ)
FROM tableA AS A 
LEFT JOIN
  ( 
    SELECT 
      col1,
      col3 
    FROM 
      sourceTable
    WHERE col2 = 'someValue_A'
  ) AS S1 
    ON A.col1 = S1.col1 
LEFT JOIN
  ( 
    SELECT 
      col1,
      col3 
    FROM 
      sourceTable
    WHERE col2 = 'someValue_B'
  ) AS S2
    ON A.col1 = S1.col1 
LEFT JOIN
  ( 
    SELECT 
      col1,
      col3 
    FROM 
      sourceTable
    WHERE col2 = 'someValue_C'
  ) AS S3
    ON A.col1 = S1.col1
WHERE
  S1.col3 IS NOT NULL OR
  S2.col3 IS NOT NULL OR
  S3.col3 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Noice but yeah even i agree that `CASE` is the way to go

Comment: @user, yeah. I would never do it like this. That's why I asked about the limitation. It feels a little like a homework assignment, in which case I probably shouldn't have given away the answer. :)